# Virtualenv OSError - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, virtualenv, miniconda

I get the following error message when trying to set up a virtual environment with virtualenv 15.0.2 but receive OSError setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1.

```
New python executable in /Users/nathmorissette/projects/tutorial/venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command /Users/nathmorissett...rial/venv/bin/python - setuptools pip wheel:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/Users/nathmorissette/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/tempfile.py", line 32, in <module>
    import io as _io
  File "/Users/nathmorissette/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/io.py", line 51, in <module>
    import _io
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/nathmorissette/projects/tutorial/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder
  Referenced from: /Users/nathmorissette/projects/tutorial/venv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/nathmorissette/miniconda2/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==15.0.2', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/Users/nathmorissette/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-15.0.2-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 711, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/Users/nathmorissette/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-15.0.2-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 944, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "/Users/nathmorissette/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-15.0.2-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 900, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "/Users/nathmorissette/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv-15.0.2-py2.7.egg/virtualenv.py", line 795, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command /Users/nathmorissett...rial/venv/bin/python - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally resorted to using conda to set up an environment rather than virtualenv.  Apparently virtualenv is not compatible with anaconda.

Info in this link helped me set it up:

https://uoa-eresearch.github.io/eresearch-cookbook/recipe/2014/11/20/conda/

Answer (score 30):

I tried for hours, read lots of posts and finally find a way out.

`pip uninstall virtualenv
conda install virtualenv`

The reason is the virtualenv installed by pip is not compatible with conda.
I don't know more details, but it works for me.

Comment: Thank you @FrankZhu . I was facing the same issue and your answer helped me to resolve that.

Comment: For those whishing to understand differences between pip and conda here is a useful link: https://www.anaconda.com/understanding-conda-and-pip/

This make me ask the question: Why using virtualenv when conda already provides you environment isolation features?

Answer (score 17):

I got this error while having several python versions installed on my mac. Specifying which python version to be used for your new virtual environment solves the issue.

By specifying the absolute python path:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python2.7 venv
```

or use your default python link:

```
virtualenv -p python3 venv
```

Answer (score 13):

I had this same issue while installing requirements from `requirements.txt`.

This was what solved the problem for me.

1. `pip install --upgrade virtualenv`
2. `pip install --upgrade pip`
3. After doing this, if you ever get errors while trying to install a dependency like below

> THESE PACKAGES DO NOT MATCH THE HASHES FROM THE REQUIREMENTS FILE. If you have updated the package versions, please update the hashes. Otherwise, examine the package contents carefully; someone may have tampered with them.
>       pbr==3.1.1 from https://pypi.python.org/packages/0c/5d/b077dbf309993d52c1d71e6bf6fe443a8029ea215135ebbe0b1b10e7aefc/pbr-3.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=75a0f55856bfc9220af0d01244afec43 (from -r requirements-test.txt (line 52)):
>
> Expected sha256 60c25b7dfd054ef9bb0ae327af949dd4676aa09ac3a9471cdc871d8a9213f9ac
>           Expected     or 05f61c71aaefc02d8e37c0a3eeb9815ff526ea28b3b76324769e6158d7f95be1
>
> Got        b11776d9eb0e7b3988bb7bdef4e2d40cf8c168214374d12d1c4495c1346ac10b
>
> ERROR: could not install deps [-rrequirements-test.txt]; v = InvocationError('/app/.tox/py27/bin/pip install -rrequirements-test.txt (see /app/.tox/py27/log/py27-1.log)', 1)
>
> ________________________________ summary _______________________________
>
> ERROR:   py27: could not install deps [-rrequirements-test.txt]; v = InvocationError('/app/.tox/py27/bin/pip install -rrequirements-test.txt (see /app/.tox/py27/log/py27-1.log)', 1)

Then use `pip --no-cache-dir install <package-name>` to install the package; where `<package-name>` is the name of the package you want to install.

e.g `pip --no-cache-dir install pbr`

Answer (score 4):

Simply you can do this:

> Python 2: **virtualenv env**
>
> Python 3 : **python3 -m venv env**

Answer (score 3):

Removal of ~/.pydistutils.cfg worked for me.

See the following link (last answer):
https://github.com/Homebrew/legacy-homebrew/issues/44836

Answer (score 2):

Running

```
conda install -c anaconda virtualenv=15.1.0
```

worked for me.

This is because virtualenv doesnt work with pip while conda exists on your system.

Comment: The most simple and best solution I think

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error even with no anaconda installed. After a few minutes i realized that i was trying to create a virtualenv folder (C:/myname/virtual_folder) at the same **directory level** as was my Python installation folder (C:/myname/python27) .

So I just created a folder and then inside of it (C:/myname/prefolder/..) i run ("virtualenv virtual_folder") with no issues .

Answer (score 0):

You can get virtualenv to work with conda if you downgrade python to 2.7.9:

```
$pip install python=2.7.9
```

You can see the status of this issue on conda's github: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1367

Answer (score 0):

This will work for virtualenv pip wheel errorcode1 problems and also E unable to locate package problems

```
apt-get update

apt-get install python-software-properties

apt-get install apt-file

apt-file update

apt-get install software-properties-common

apt-get install <your filename>
```

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda does seem to sometimes mess up with virtualenv.

Specifying the python system version `/usr/bin/python3.5` instead of the conda one solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can save yourself from all this hustle by just downloading latest version of python, install it before you begin openstack or devstack installation. Go to https://www.python.org/downloads/. Installing latest version of python will replace the older version and install all the libraries you need. This saved me four days of trying to install devstack

Answer (score 0):

For 3.7.3, i did a pip install --upgrade pip (from 18.1 to 19.1)

Then i did the required installation and it worked (for pyinstaller)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. The reason was with invalid path of python. Fixed it with removing python to 'c:\python37' from appdata. It cuz you have unicode chars in the path name.