# Error when using the command "virtualenv venv" to create Python virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I used the command `virtualenv venv` to create the Python virtual environment, the following error occurred:

```
D:\Flask>virtualenv venv
Using base prefix 'd:\\APP\\python'
New python executable in D:\Flask\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
  Complete output from command D:\Flask\venv\Scripts\python.exe - setuptools pip wheel:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'pkgutil'
----------------------------------------
...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\APP\python\lib\runpy.py", line 170, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "d:\APP\python\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\APP\python\Scripts\virtualenv.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "d:\APP\python\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 713, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "d:\APP\python\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 945, in create_environment
    download=download,
  File "d:\APP\python\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 901, in install_wheel
    call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)
  File "d:\APP\python\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py", line 797, in call_subprocess
    % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode))
OSError: Command D:\Flask\venv\Scripts\python.exe - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1
```

I googled it but didn't find a solution. Does anyone know how to deal with it?

Comment: The error message is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/37637872 Did you try that solution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Virtualenv OSError - setuptools pip wheel failed with error code 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37637872/virtualenv-oserror-setuptools-pip-wheel-failed-with-error-code-1)

Answer (score 4):

use `python -m venv path/to/your/venv` to create a virtual environment and then activate it with `path/to/your/venv/Scripts/activate.bat` (`deactivate` for quitting the venv)

example:

```
python -m venv test
test\Scripts\activate.bat
(test) deactivate
```

Comment: Thanks, I used venv instead virtualenv to creat. It works