# Error while creating the virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, virtual-environment

When I try to create a virtual environment via virtualenv I get an error:

> C:\Users\Фёдор\Desktop\project>virtualenv venv Using base prefix
>   'c:\users\фёдор\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32' New
>   python executable in
>   C:\Users\Фёдор\Desktop\project\venv\Scripts\python.exe Installing
>   setuptools, pip, wheel...   Complete output from command
>   C:\Users\Фёдор\Deskt...v\Scripts\python.exe - setuptools pip wheel:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 3, in
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkgutil'
>
> ---------------------------------------- ...Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done. Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:\users\фёдор\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py",
>   line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", mod_spec)   File "c:\users\фёдор\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\runpy.py",
>   line 85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)   File "c:\users\фёдор\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\Scripts\virtualenv.exe__main__.py",
>   line 9, in    File
>   "c:\users\фёдор\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py",
>   line 712, in main
>       symlink=options.symlink)   File "c:\users\фёдор\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py",
>   line 947, in create_environment
>       download=download,   File "c:\users\фёдор\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py",
>   line 904, in install_wheel
>       call_subprocess(cmd, show_stdout=False, extra_env=env, stdin=SCRIPT)   File
>   "c:\users\фёдор\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-packages\virtualenv.py",
>   line 796, in call_subprocess
>       % (cmd_desc, proc.returncode)) OSError: Command C:\Users\Фёдор\Deskt...v\Scripts\python.exe - setuptools pip wheel
>   failed with error code 1

Why does this happen: `pip can not download "pkgutil" module`

The folder with the virtual environment is created but the command `venv/scripts/activate` does not work.

Comment: How did you create the virtualenv?
Further, [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43143829/2402281) may help you out.

Comment: I created it by cmd command: virtualenv venv

Comment: Thank you. You helped me a lot!)