# Issue with installing virtualenv for DJango

Tags: python, django, pip, virtualenv

I am installing virtualenv for my DJango project. 
I have used:

```
    virtualenv venv

    virtualenv venv -p {myPath}Python/Python37-32/python
```

but all of theese have thrown the same error:

```
    Complete output from command E:\DJango\firstTutor...2\Scripts\python.exe - setuptools pip wheel:
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 3, in <module>
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkgutil'
```

I am using the latest versions of Python, pip and virtualenv.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error when using the command "virtualenv venv" to create Python virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43142145/error-when-using-the-command-virtualenv-venv-to-create-python-virtual-environm)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvirtualenv%5D+ModuleNotFoundError%3A+No+module+named+pkgutil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using virtualenv try using the built in python `venv`. I.e:

```
python3 -m venv name_of_virtual_environment
```

If you don't have python3 added to path then replace it with the path to your python.exe

`pkgutil` is a built-in module so it does not need to be installed when creating a new virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this
python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment

Answer (score 0):

```
python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment
```

For more info you can go below link

[https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html]